# Создание записей в связанных моделях

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

В моделях:

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :rooms
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :hotel
end
```

В контролере:

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_room, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  ...

  def create
    hotel = Hotel.find_by(params[:hotel_id])
    @room = hotel.rooms.build(room_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @room.save
        format.html { redirect_to @room, notice: 'Room was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  ...

  private
    def set_room
      @room = Room.find(params[:id])
    end

    def room_params
      params.require(:room).permit(:hotel_id => params[:hotel_id])
    end
end
```

Во вьюхе hotel/:id/show:

```
<%= form_for ([@hotel, @hotel.rooms.build]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Возникает ошибка

> param is missing or the value is empty: room

в строке

```
params.require(:room).permit(:hotel_id => params[:hotel_id])
```

Можно было бы передать hotel_id в форме при помощи text_hidden но ведь можно и без этого обойтись?

**Update**

> Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> {"utf8"=>"✓", 
>   "authenticity_token"=>"p9qFzAHI34aylqeRleB9xgJeZyedAJZCl2SkcEoU0b+cuMrbm5qJDvqtVzWyxjjfTqnuMhWOmToDdJOZcZ41Tw==",
>   "commit"=>"Create Room",  "hotel_id"=>"2"}

Comment: Какого содержимое тела POST запроса? Я предполагаю, что там нет параметра с именем `room`

Comment: Видимо да. Теперь вопрос как его туда передать?

Comment: Когда вы выполяете строку `hotel = Hotel.find_by(params[:hotel_id])` - вы находите отель ID, переданным в `POST`. А когда выполняете `@room = hotel.rooms.build(room_params)` - строите новый объекта класса `Room`, содержащий `hotel_id`. То есть при таком создании `Room`, `room_params` передавать не нужно.